# An underscore is added to link when checking it

Tags: php

I am making a simple link checker to check thousands of direct links for files in a site I am managing now. All files are from archive_org. I made a textarea

```
<table width="100%"> <tr><td>URLs to check:</td><td><textarea name="myurl" id="myurl" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea></td></tr> 
<tr><td align="center" colspan="2"><br/><input class="text" type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Check links"></td></tr> </table>
```

and all links on it will be stored in an array called $url (each url is put in a new line)

```
$url = explode("\n", $_POST['myurl']);
```

I printed it using print_r and links inside the array are the same as entered without any character added.

I checked the urls using two methods: fopen() and curl functions, and no matter how many links I put, the program see all links are broken except for the last one. The last link in the array is the only one which is checked correctly.

I used get_headers function, and I noticed that all links (except for the last one) have underscore (_) added to their end. The get_headers code is:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($url);$i++) {
   $headers = @get_headers($url[$i]);
   $headers = (is_array($headers)) ? implode( "\n ", $headers) : $headers;
   print_r($headers);
   echo "<br /><br />";   
    }
```

In the headers I noticed the links are as such:

> HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily Server: nginx/1.1.19 Date: Mon, 02 Sep 2013 10:46:40 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2 Accept-Ranges: bytes Location: http://ia600308.us.archive[dot]org/23/items/historyofthedecl00731gut/1dfre012103.mp3_ X-Cache: MISS from Dataprolinks X-Cache: MISS from AIMAN-DPL X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from AIMAN-DPL:3128 Connection: close HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found Server: nginx/1.1.19 Date: Mon, 02 Sep 2013 10:46:41 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2 Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=s2j3ct95vdji0ua89f32grd984; path=/; domain=.archive.org Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache X-Cache: MISS from Dataprolinks X-Cache: MISS from AIMAN-DPL X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from AIMAN-DPL:3128 Connection: close

There is an underscore added to the link, except for the header of the last url, no underscore is added. I guess this underscore is responsible for the checking error.

Where am I making mistakes?

Comment: so user enters each URL per one line?

Comment: Is it you means POSTed URLs does not end with underscore. But you get the information by `get_header()` with underscore in all links except the last URL you POST. Is it??

Comment: What is the value of $_POST['myurl'] after user submit?

Comment: I retrieved thousands of urls fron database and want to check them all at once, each url is in new line. The posted urls don't end with underscore.

Comment: @invisal It is http://archivedotorg/download/historyofthedecl00731gut/1dfre011103.mp3 without undercore at the end.

Comment: @AllenChak yes exactly.

Comment: The form looks like...?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams <table width="100%"> 
          <tr><td>URLs to check:</td><td><textarea name="myurl" id="myurl" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea></td></tr> 
          <tr><td align="center" colspan="2"><br/><input class="text" type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Check links"></td></tr> 
        </table>

Comment: What is you execute PHP platform? Linux? WinNT?? And PHP version.

Comment: The first thing you should check is `var_dump($_POST['myurl'], $url);`.

Comment: @AllenChak I am using linux on my website (php ver 5.2.17) and wamp in my computer (php ver 5.3.13). Both give the same result.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I did it and all links are right without underscore added.

Comment: Then, where exactly do you see those underscore added? In the output for `get_headers()`? But `get_headers()` is supposed to return, well, HTTP headers, not URLs... :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario the content of header contains the url: HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily Server: nginx/1.1.19 Date: Mon, 02 Sep 2013 10:46:40 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2 Accept-Ranges: bytes Location: http://ia600308.us.archive.org/23/items/historyofthedecl00731gut/1dfre012103.mp3_ X-Cache: .... and more data. The header of the last url doesn't have underscore added to the link. The main problem is that when checking my links, the result is all are broken except last one. So i got headers to see what the problem is and saw this underscore added

Comment: Is it possible that you edit the original question when you want to add further details? Code in comments is unreadable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your cases, I guess you POST the URLs in Window, when you press **"ENTER"** key to separate the links, the **"ENTER"** as **"\r\n"**. In WWW, there must not include the **"\r"**, therefore somewhere(php? curl? I have no idea about that.) convert it into **"_"**.

```
<?php

$urls = array();
$urls[] = 'http://archive.org/download/historyofthedecl00731gut/1dfre011103.mp3';
$urls[] = 'http://archive.org/download/historyofthedecl00731gut/1dfre000103.txt';
$urls[] = 'http://archive.org/download/historyofthedecl00731gut/1dfre082103.mp3';
$urls[] = 'http://archive.org/download/historyofthedecl00731gut/1dfre001103.txt';
$urls[] = 'http://archive.org/download/historyofthedecl00731gut/1dfre141103.mp3';

print("<pre>" .print_r($urls, 1). "</pre><br /><br />");

foreach($urls as $url){
    //ensure each url only start with ONE _ and end with ONE _
    print("<pre>_" . $url . "_</pre>");
    $header = array();
    $headers = @get_headers($url);
    print("<pre>" .print_r($headers, 1). "</pre><br /><br />");
}

?>
```

You can use my code to have a simple test: each link will be printed with **"_"** both in start and end. Then proof my explain. How to fix: just add the `strip_tags(nl2br($url))` to remove the **"\r"**, **"\n"**.

[image: Simple result]

Comment: It works. Thank you! The problem was with the addition of /r/n.